# How to create repository instance in JackRabbit Oak using MicroKernel

Tags: jackrabbit, jcr, content-repository

According to JackRabbit Oak official [documentation](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/oak/docs/construct.html), one of the ways of creating `Repository` instance is to create a `MicroKernel` object and pass it to `JCR's` parameterized constructor like this:

```
MicroKernel kernel = ...;
Repository repository = new Jcr(kernel).createRepository();
```

But looking at the JCR class [javadocs](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/oak/docs/apidocs/index.html), i can't find any constructor which takes an object of type `MicroKernel`.

So my questions is :

- How can we get a repository object using `MicroKernel` in JackRabbit Oak(**not
     JackRabbit 2.0**).

Note: I want a repository which uses normal file system as the content storage medium.

Answer (score 3):

The documentations is unfortunately lagging behind in some areas. The `MicroKernel` interface has been superseded by the `NodeStore`interface in Oak.

For file system persistence you'd use the `SegmentNodeStore`. Have a look at how the respective test cases [set up the repository](https://github.com/apache/jackrabbit-oak/blob/a6798b166514148e31c16153eabbf42d2de60a4b/oak-jcr/src/test/java/org/apache/jackrabbit/oak/jcr/OakTarMKRepositoryStub.java#L62).

In a nutshell:

```
File directory = ...
NodeStore store = new FileStore(directory, 1, false);
Jcr jcr = new Jcr(new Oak(new SegmentNodeStore(store)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the `MicroKernelImpl` public no-arg constructor to create an in-memory kernel instance:

```java
MicroKernel kernel = new MicroKernelImpl();
Repository repository = new Jcr(kernel).createRepository();
```

Alternativelly, you can use the `OAK` class entry to create a `Repository`:

```java
MicroKernel kernel = new MicroKernelImpl();
Repository repo = new Oak(kernel).createRepository();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but i don't find any constructor in `JCR` class which takes `MicroKernel` type as argument.

Comment: Which Jackarabbit OAK version are you using?

Comment: Note the update of my answer for using the `org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.Oak` class.